# Capistrano doesn't abort deployment when task fails

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

Capistrano doesn't abort when the executed commands exit status is different than 0. And continues to deployment. How can I abort the deployment when the executed command fails, returns an exit status different than 0?

I tried test, execute, capture commands but couldn't make it happened. Here is the recent code that I am testing failure, I actually running real jobs. When I try to execute in on the remote server, the exit status is 1.

```
   desc "Command to abort"
   task :aborting_command do
      on roles(:all) do |host|
            within release_path do
               execute("false")
            end
         end
      end
   end
```

Output of it:

```
INFO [0ea66341] Running /usr/bin/env false on remote-server.xxx
DEBUG [0ea66341] Command: cd /projectdir/releases/20160315140516 && /usr/bin/env false
INFO [0ea66341] Finished in 0.044 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

With --trace:

```
** Invoke deploy:aborting_command (first_time)
** Execute deploy:aborting_command
DEBUG [d5f30008] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /projectdir/releases/20160315140254; then echo "Directory does not exist '/projectdir/releases/20160315140254'" 1>&2; false; fi on remote-server.xxx
DEBUG [d5f30008] Command: if test ! -d /projectdir/releases/20160315140254; then echo "Directory does not exist '/projectdir/releases/20160315140254'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [d5f30008] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [50a2e035] Running /usr/bin/env false on remote-server.xxx
DEBUG [50a2e035] Command: cd /projectdir
INFO [50a2e035] Finished in 0.043 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Working on with Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)

Comment: I'm confused. Your code works for me. It simply exits upon running the command.

Comment: I am using ssh forward agent to connect to remote and run commands, can that be a problem? I have tried also with setting false but no luck.